# Single channel textures on iOS and OpenGL ES 3

Tags: ios, opengl-es, textures

These OpenGL ES formats are driving me nuts... I upgraded my project to ES 3 from ES 2, so apparently you have to declare the internal format with a sized type... According to https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/docbook4/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml these combinations are perfectly valid:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
...
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16F, width, height, 0, GL_RED, GL_HALF_FLOAT, NULL);
```

But they give me `GL_INVALID_OPERATION`. Single channel textures in ES are poorly documented by Khronos/Apple and the community barely uses them. If there is another soul out there that attempted to use them and succeeded please let me know. I wish I could just use Metal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh, being on a chip < A7 was the explanation of the errors. [No OpenGL 3.0 on that](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/OpenGLESPlatforms/OpenGLESPlatforms.html).